# which object method of interface implementation will be called

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I have a code like below in project. Here by casting with interface we are calling the method authenticate() of the service IAuthenticateService. Now there are 5 subclasses which have the same method implementation and Implementing the same interface IAuthenticateService. By seeing the code how will I come to know which class method implementation has been called? I'm little bit confused of interface design.

```
((IAuthenticateService) AuthServiceApp.getInstance().getContext()
                    .getService(ServiceEnum.CredentialService.name()))
                    .authenticate(inputParams);
```

Comment: You don't need to know, just follow the contract you are interested in *what* they do and not in *how*. BTW You can only know in runtime execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't know just by reading this code.

But, the program will know at runtime which implementation to call : the object returned by `AuthServiceApp.getInstance().getContext()` will have a type, which one will have a single implementation of the method `getService`, and this implementation will be called.

As a programmer, you don't need to know more. The [programming by contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) paradigm allows you not to bother about which implementation will be called. All you need to know is that given a certain environment, you will get an instance of a context on which you can call `getService()`, AND it will provide you with a service.

The rest is details, you don't have to worry about it.

Of course, when you are debugging, that's a different story : you want to know which implementation is executed as it might be buggy. In that case, just follow the debugger to see which code is really executed, but otherwise, you should not care, that's all what polymorphism is about : gaining abstraction.

Comment: @Snicolus- thanks a lot for the explanation. As you said there is a single implementation of method getService() and it's defined by an abstract class IMapService. Now there are 3 base classes of IMapService class and each implementing the authenticate() method. How the compiler on runtime calling the correct implementation? Using debugger of course I'm able to find out the correct class calling implementing method.

Comment: It's not about correctness. The implementation is given. Sorry, not so clear. Debug your could and follow it step by step, you will catch it.

Comment: @snicolas- Using debugger I'm able to find out the actual method call. What I'm not clear about is how jvm on runtime invoking the class which implements the method. Sorry my previous comment posted unfinished.

Comment: I think, the whole mystery for you lies in getInstance() or getService(). Try to look at those methods bodies, you will see what is the criteria to switch from an implementation to an other.

Answer (score 0):

Well you not being able to tell what implementation of IAuthentication is being returned is the whole point of interfaces.  We use interfaces to segment parts of code away from each other.  This makes programs more extensible and versatile which drives code reuse.  It is a very powerful concept and the corner stone of modern software development.  The client (the code using the interface's methods) does not care what is on the other side of the interface (ie the implementer of the interface).  This allows for the client side to change at runtime.  The fact that you don't know is what gives its power.  In order to understand this concept you have to think about how the compiler works and what it does when it compiles code.

In compiled languages the compiler translates source code into machine instructions.  When it is translating a method into a machine code the method receives an address in memory where the method starts.  When another piece of code calls that method that memory address is written in the code on the client code.  That memory address is fixed so that piece of code can't call any other method at runtime.  It will always call that one method and never a different method.

For example say we have something like this:

```
private int someMethod() { ... }
```

The compiler says someMethod is located at 003.  So when it's compiling code like this:

```
public myMethod() {
    this.someMethod();
}
```

It says myMethod calls someMethod, and looks up where in memory someMethod lives.  Roughly it will write out something like:

```
// myMethod
call 003
```

Now that method invocation (aka call site) can only ever call someMethod forever.  It will never call any other method but that exact method.

But in OO languages we can vary which actual method is called at runtime.  That means the compiler can't write that memory address into the callers code when it is compiling the class.  Instead it has to look up that method address at runtime.  How it does that is by looking up the method by name in the object it is passed at runtime.  So the compiler might do something like this:

```
// myMethod
methodAddress = this.methodsAddresses['someMethod']
call methodAddress
```

It's that lookup (sometimes called the virtual pointer table) that enables methods to change depending on what someObject points to, and that lookup allows it to vary at runtime.

This is all well and good until you need to debug something.  If you are trying to debug something its easiest if you use a debugger, and drop a break point in your client code and you can easily look at that an many other things along with stepping into the code.  You can also print someObject.getClass().getName() to find the name, but that is just the beginning if you are debugging.